# extract json attribute and turn it into string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
var json = {"result": [
            {
                "name": "3",
                "id": "1"
            },
            {
                "name": "3",
                "id": "2"
            }
        ]}
```

How can get loop through this json to get the id and turn it into a string?

```
"1,2"
```

Comment: Post what have you tried? SO is not a free coding service...

Comment: I tried google but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var json = {
    "result": [
        {
            "name": "3",
            "id": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "3",
            "id": "2"
        }
]};
var output = json.result.map(function(item) {
    return item.id;
}).filter(function(id) {
    return id;
}).join(',');
```

Comment: if the id is "", it will skip that. how to produce like 1,2,"",2,1 ?

Comment: @naniyaw updated the answer that will skip if id is `""` or if there is no id.

Comment: `filter(Boolean)` would be more straighforward.

Comment: @torazaburo didn't know that you can do this way. always learning something new.